# How to turn Tkinter entry from string to integer

Tags: python

I am making an auto clicker which asks two questions, delay and clicks per second. But when I try to make the input of the entry go to the code that says how much clicks per second it can't because it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    clicks = int(entry) 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Entry'
```

Here is the code:

```
import pynput
import time
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
Height = 500
width = 600





def test_function(delay):
    from pynput.mouse import Button,Controller
    mouse = Controller()
    time.sleep(float(delay))
    mouse.click(Button.left, (int(clicks)))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Height, width=width)


canvas.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.21)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4)


label = tk.Label(root, text="Tech AutoClicker")
label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0)
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Clicks per sec:")
label2.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.2,)
label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Delay until starting (in seconds):")
label3.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.4)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Start Auto clicker", bg="#84f47c", fg="green", command=lambda: test_function(entry2 and entry.get()))
button.pack()
clicks = int(entry)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is in the error. `'entry'` is not a number. To use `int()` the argument may **only** contain a string with number characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `entry` variable holds an object of the widget class `Entry`. You need to get the text value of the widget, using its `get()` method and then pass it to `int()` function:

```
clicks = int(entry.get())
```

In your example, in the line that you try to get the text of the `Entry`, it will have no value (empty string) so it won't be able to be converted to int.

This is an example of how you could use the `Entry` widget properly:

```
import tkinter


def fun():
    clicks = int(entry.get())
    print(clicks)


root = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(root, text='click me', command=fun)
button.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It won't work" it says clicks = int(entry.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: That happens because the text you inserted, cannot be converted to int. You have to input digits. Try the example i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement from `tk` is taken out and put at start of the script as the python styling convetion [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) subscribes. Removing clicks and lambda functions made when mouse is on the botton autorun your scripts output.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pynput, time
from   pynput.mouse import Button,Controller

def test_function():
    mouse = Controller()
#    time.sleep(float(delay))  # if delay is set to e.g. 2.5. You get results after you close the window.
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)   # on MacOS 1= 2.
    print ('User-input 1: "%s" , Ui2: "%s".' % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

# Main GUI
root   = tk.Tk()
Height = 500
width  = 600

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Height, width=width)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Tech AutoClicker")
label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0)

# GUI entity 1 - user input
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Clicks per sec :")
label2.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.2)
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.21)
#print ('2 : %s' % e1)

# GUI entity 2 - user input
label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Delay until starting (in seconds) :")
label3.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.4)
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4)

# GUI entity 3 - button
button   = tk.Button(root, text="Start Auto Click", bg="#84f47c", fg="green", command=test_function)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The answer from elgaspar will work if `clicks = str(entry)`:

```
import tkinter

def fun():
    clicks = str(entry)
    print(clicks)

root = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(root, text='click me', command=fun)
button.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/qq/PycharmProjects/Auto clicker/trying.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Start Auto clicker", bg="#84f47c", fg="green", command=lambda: test_function(entry2 and entry1.get()))
  File "C:/Users/qq/PycharmProjects/Auto clicker/trying.py", line 13, in test_function
    mouse.click(Button.left, (int(clicks)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.!entry'

Comment: its fixed. I've rearranges a few things for you to meet python styling conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the Entry widget and use the 'get' method:

```
class IntEntry(tkinter.Entry):
    def get(self):
        val = super().get()
        return int(val)

entry = IntEntry(root)
entry.pack()

# type number in

my_number = entry.get()
```

Don't forget to handle cases where the user did not put in an integer.